# First Time Boot Screen Configuration

Tags: setup, screen

I want to get a RCA screen and connect through an adapter cable to the 3.5mm jack. This will be my first time setting up the pi. My question is will this work or does it automatically only send out to HDMI unless configured (which I obviously can't do since I don't have a HDMI screen)? In other words I am doing my first setup of raspberry pi and am wondering if by default the pi also sends out video to the 3.5mm jack also?

Comment: Even if it were not to output analogue video (which I am not sure about right now) you could always `ssh` into it and configure it that way without a HDMI display. Just be sure to pick an OS that has `sshd` up and running per default.

Comment: Does raspbian have that in the Noobs package?

Comment: @EinsteinJr. Yes, Raspbian includes `sshd`. However, you *may* (not sure) have to enable in `raspi-config` on the initial time you boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all of my experiences, the Pi will send the signal out to whichever cable it detects as being active (connected to a display.)

However, if there is no display connected, it defaults to HDMI. And, judging by your comment, you're using NOOBS, which automatically defaults to HDMI even if there isn't a display connected. From the [NOOBS Github](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs) page:

> By default, NOOBS will output over HDMI at your display’s preferred
>   resolution, even if no HDMI display is connected. If you do not see
>   any output on your HDMI display or are using the composite output,
>   press 1, 2, 3 or 4 on your keyboard to select HDMI preferred mode,
>   HDMI safe mode, composite PAL mode or composite NTSC mode
>   respectively.

- <kbd>1</kbd> to select **HDMI preferred** mode
- <kbd>2</kbd> to select **HDMI safe** mode
- <kbd>3</kbd> to select **Composite PAL** mode
- <kbd>4</kbd> to select **Composite NTSC** mode

or, you can set the preferred output mode *prior* to booting NOOBS by editing the the `recovery.cmdline` file in the root NOOBS directory prior to booting NOOBS and tacking on the following line to the end: `display=<DISPLAYMODENUM>`. `DISPLAYMODENUM` being 1-4, same as the buttons, each causes NOOBS to default to a different display mode.

Comment: So even if I just got my pi and haven't done anything as far as setup, I can plug in the RCA display and a keyboard and mouse and power supply, click 3 on the keyboard and it will transmit screen data to 3.5mm jack?

Comment: @EinsteinJr. In theory, yes, that should work! Or, if it doesn't, you can always edit the file prior to booting! Best of luck!

Comment: ohhhhhhh, I get it!!!! Somehow I never thought of editing the files on the sd card from a PC. Well, live and learn. Thanks!

Comment: @EinsteinJr. Yup! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add to RPi Awsomeness(cool name) answer. When the pi boots, a green led will flicker. After it does, you keep pressing the shift key until it blinks a lot. Then you can press 1/2/3/4. This confuzled me for a while so I thought I would post it. Hope it helps.

Comment: This probably should have been a comment for next time. So your saying you have to press shift too?